# The process com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext hogs Mac CPU but cannot be killed or stopped from launching

Tags: mac, vpn, cpu

MacBookPro16,1 running Big Sur 11.3.1 (20E241)

This job consumes huge amounts of CPU off and on (see attached image from my Activity Monitor), often causing my laptop fans to engage to cool the processor. This is generally when the App itself (Anyconnect) is not running. The program launches automatically and relaunches every time I kill it, restart, etc. I have tried fancier things like removing the Cisco elements from launch directories etc, but it does not have any effect.

There are several discussions online about this problem, but none of the proposed solutions have helped me:

[Stop Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client from starting up automatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202296/stop-cisco-anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-from-starting-up-automatically)

https://dannyda.com/2020/10/28/how-to-disable-cisco-anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-autostart-on-macos-stop-cisco-anyconnect-start-on-boot-on-macos/

I've tried all the solutions I've found online (including those in the above links), but nothing stops it. Only uninstalling AnyConnect works, but I need the Cisco VPN to work remotely with my organization.

Anyone worked this out (for real?)

t3s
[image: cpu usage]

Comment: What an awful, awful application. Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Press `Don't allow` When Cisco asks `Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter” Would Like to Filter Network Content`.

If you do so it creates `Network Setting`s that automatically launches this CPU-consuming `com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext`.

To revert it :

1. Go to System `Preferences -> Network`
2. Observe several instances starting with `Cisco..` next to `Wi-Fi`
3. Delete all of them with `-` button beneath
4. Press `Apply`
5. If any `Cisco` instances appears again, delete it again; Press `Apply`
6. Check for `com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext` in `Activity Monitor` and kill it if needed
7. NEVER! Allow `Cisco` to Filter Network Content again
   (for some reason it lacks of Don't ask again checkbox)

Comment: So far, this seems to have solved it. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: It works, but happens again when I restart my computer. Also, that message box appears often. :/

Comment: Same here. It came back for me. Cisco AnyConnect 4.9.5042 & macOS 11.4 (20F71).

Comment: Can anyone talk to the impact of disabling?  Without the filter and/or DNS proxy, am I getting the expected protections/routings?

Comment: if I click "Don't Allow", it keeps asking.

Comment: After I killed `com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext` and removed the `Cisco...` instances in the Network setting, I could not connect to the SVN anymore for which Cisco was configured.

Comment: These options don't seem to be available in Ventura.

Answer (score 66):

I think I’ve found a fix.

1. Go into the Applications folder and open the Cisco folder.
2. Delete the Cisco Socket Filter application but NOT the Anyconnect client.

I’ve not had the issue since and the VPN is working fine.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Simple and effective

Comment: The only one that worked

Comment: A huge god-damn thank you! It was annoying me for a year!!!

Comment: This basically means uninstalling the Socket Filter app and its system extensions. What a magnificent job by Cisco people! /s

Comment: Just confirmed this is working on Ventura 13.5.2.
I understand that there are times when socket filtering is relevant for domain laptops. But for me as an external consultant using "my own" laptop to connect to customer servers it is completely unreasonable

Answer (score 15):

Personally, I had success from the following:

***NOTE:* You will need Administrator access on your Mac to accomplish these instructions**

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Kill the running process
3. Open Network Prefs
4. Remove all instances of it with the [-] button, and click apply
5. Open Terminal
6. Change permissions on the application Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter.app

```
    cd /Applications/Cisco
    sudo chmod 0644 "./Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter.app"
    sudo chown ${USER}:staff "./Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter.app"
    exit
```

This will change ownership of the app to your personal account, and alter its permissions such that your account can read or write to it, but nobody, including you or the system groups, and execute it. It's a paperweight.

But since my company has a script that verifies its existence (even if it can't run it itself or it's not running at that moment) I don't care to delete it and have to explain myself.

It does not impact my AnyConnect/ability to access the corporate VPN whatsoever, doesn't trip any red flags with CorpSec (YMMV), and persists after reboot.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @agarza ... thank you? I didn't even know that one COULD edit someone else's post! I assume you're a mod or admin, but after looking at the diff, I can see why you chose to clean it up.  I'd been in a bit of dash out the door as I was trying to whip that out. Appreciate the polish (and your foregoing the well-deserved lambaste of my typographic and grammatical skills in the comments, lol). ❤️

Comment: After so much [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/reputation), users will get different [privileges](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). So really, the community as a whole tends to the upkeep of the individual Stacks.

Comment: I'm not sure this works on Ventura (13.0.1). There seems to be extra permissions required to make this modification. I'm seeing ```$ sudo chmod 0644 "./Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter.app"
chmod: Unable to change file mode on ./Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter.app: Operation not permitted```

Comment: NB - You need to ensure that Terminal.app (or equivalent terminal) has permissions to `update or delete other applications`. This is under `System Settings > Privacy & Security > App Management`

Comment: @hafichuk: hey man, thanks so much for spotting that issue, and even more for returning with the answer to it after you determined what it was. I've since changed contracts (this particular issue isn't one for me, at least for the moment), but I've run into it on umpteen other gigs; I'm sure it will be again. I didn't know Ventura reduced the execution perms, either, and your note here just solved a wholly-unrelated issue I WAS experiencing. Thanks, brother! Good looking out!

Comment: This is genius! I tried and can verify this also works very well too!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using AnyConnect 4.10.x, I encountered the same problem and it was temporarily resolved by reverting back to version 4.9.06037

If your 4.9.x client automatically updates, you can set `bypassDownloader` to be `true` in `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/AnyConnectLocalPolicy.xml` to keep it at 4.9.x

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem. In case anyone couldn't find old version, here is a [link from TU Graz university](https://ftp.tugraz.at/tu-graz/vpn/)

Comment: Unfortunately, as of yesterday, it looks like the TU Graz FTP no longer has the 4.9.x client.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Nikitas answer, you should also remove the system extension:

1. Go to CMD
2. Execute

   ```
   systemextensionsctl list
   ```
3. Look for TEAMID for BUNDLEID com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext
4. Execute

   ```
   sudo systemextensionsctl uninstall TEAMID com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext
   ```

Note: As of September 1, 2020, running the systemextensionsctl uninstall command requires [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899) (SIP) to be disabled. This limitation is supposed to be removed by Apple at some point in the very near future.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the [Enterprise release notes for macOS Ventura 13.3](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213327) calls out a fix in macOS 13.3:

> Resolves an issue where using Cisco AnyConnect could cause high CPU usage.

Figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: What’s the fix?  Is an update necessary?  If so, which version.  It’s always best to include the relevant details rather than send folks off-site to get the answer.

Comment: High CPU usage by Cisco AnyConnect (now renamed to Cisco Secure Client) has been an issue under Ventura. I thought it was pretty clear that the fix I was referring to was upgrading to Ventura release 13.3, since in the particular instance I was referring to, it was an OS-related issue.

Comment: The way it reads, especially with the word “Enterprise” don’t resonate with basic users unless they are in the IT space.  I worked in large enterprise environments and I guarantee most users, wouldn’t have known what “enterprise” referred to

Comment: That's fair; but AnyConnect is definitely an "Enterprise" application, so that's where Apple chose to put the release note.

Answer (score 1):

I found this gist on github and it worked me very well.
https://gist.github.com/jasmas/22a4b1b12676c36074a4999c68e6a482

I copy paste the gist content here too:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo Disabling vpnagentd...
sudo launchctl disable system/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd

echo Tearing down vpnagentd...
sudo launchctl bootout system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.cisco.anyconnect.vpnagentd.plist

echo Deactivating Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter Extension...
/Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Socket\ Filter.app/Contents/MacOS/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Socket\ Filter -deactivateExt
```

All credit belongs the jasmas(https://gist.github.com/jasmas)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AnyConnect 4.10.x on Big Sur 11.5.1. What worked for me was simply to not allow Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter from loading system software (there would be a prompt in System Preferences > Security and Privacy) when you install AnyConnect.

The VPN client still works without a problem, and it seems the Socket Filter thing isn't really necessary anyways, except for the Filter Network Content feature the comment above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In Finder, control click on the Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter, and select Show Package Contents.  Expand the MacOS folder and delete the Unix Executable File.
This worked for me running Big Sur 11.6.