# Sudden massive increase in ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED errors in chrome

Tags: network, wifi, google-chrome

I've been using this mac for about 8 months with my current wifi setup. For some reason, one day I just started getting a lot of ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED errors in Google Chrome. Nothing has changed, I have not moved my router or my Mac and the devices connected to the wifi are the same, yet I still get these errors. I did not apply any software updates to my Mac so I don't know what the root cause could be.

What are some possible causes in a sudden uptick of these errors?

Comment: Not sure of the cause, but you may want to tear down the WiFi by removing it and recreating it from the Preferred Networks panel in System Preferences > Network > Advanced... . Also check to see if this particular WiFi network is at the top of the list, and remove any unused WiFi networks which show in this list.

Comment: @IconDaemon oh I think I have a plausible answer, I had to install some VPN software for my university, and it shows up on the advanced tab. I'm not actually using the VPN that often so can I keep these disabled somehow? The plugin running is "Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter", and there are three copies, two of which are running and one is not connected.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cisco AnyConnect. A word with your university's Tech Support team may be in order. Alternately, uninstall all the Cisco AnyConnect software and plugins (an uninstaller app may already be on-disk somewhere, or Cisco Support may help) and see what happens after a restart. I need to use FortiClient VPN at my school, which is a little sketchy on macOS. When things get a little weird network-wise, uninstalling it fixes it.

Comment: i'm having the same issue without any cisco product ever installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some investigation, my theory is that the socket filters installed by Cisco AnyConnect were interrupting my network connection, even if the VPN client was not active. Following the directions in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/420913/351839, I was able to delete the network sockets and kill the rogue program.

Comment: i'm having the same issue without any cisco product ever installed

Comment: @RaduUrsache do you have any other software enabled? Check your network tab on the System Preferences.

Comment: i don’t, if it would have been this easy i would have fixed it already. if i clean the network plists and reboot it seems fine for a few days then the issue comes back. only on this Mac, only in chromium based browsers. my other macs are time machine clones and those don’t experience this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is just Chrome. I have been having problems with Chrome getting ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED, but I am also having an issue with Microsoft Teams and uploading files and attachments. In both cases, if I disconnect from OpenVPN they both start working flawlessly. I can even have the ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error page up in Chrome, once I disconnect from the VPN, that page will automatically refresh and load.

I created a support bundle in Teams to separately troubleshoot that issue. When looking through the logs I saw the same error when uploading a file. That's when I knew it wasn't just Chrome.

Comment: I don't think thats the case.  If the OP is on a VPN when this is happening it can absolutely be the cause.

FYI- The newest OpenVPN client (3.4.4) fixes the issue for me.  No more ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED errors.