# Internet connection issues after update to MacOS 12.5.1

Tags: network, internet

Since I updated my macbook pro 2019 to MacOs 12.5.1 I'm experiencing strange internet connection issues:
While the connection to the router stays stable, the internet connection seems stops working every minute or so for about 30 seconds. E.g. if I'm browsing the web, suddenly a page stops loading, then after some time it works again. Also `ping google.com` doesn't work.

It's interesting that even during a time of "stable" connection, packages seem to get lost during a ping:

```
➜  ~ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.37.14): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=112.505 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=108.823 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=105.936 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=96.404 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=6 ttl=119 time=94.199 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=7 ttl=119 time=106.981 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=9 ttl=119 time=107.752 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=12 ttl=119 time=82.873 ms

64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=13 ttl=119 time=108.548 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=15 ttl=119 time=78.476 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.37.14: icmp_seq=16 ttl=119 time=133.047 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 11 packets received, 35.3% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 78.476/103.231/133.047/14.244 ms
```

What I've tried so far:

- Turning off/on laptop and router
- Use another laptop account
- Connect to router with cable
- Connect with an entirely different router
- Resetting SMC

Here is my ifconfig:

```
➜  ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 3e:22:fb:69:9e:93 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 3c:22:fb:69:9e:93 
    inet6 fe80::875:9cf5:2937:d794%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.2.103 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 2003:e7:6715:7d2:1c91:8470:b82:ff7b prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 2003:e7:6715:7d2:8df0:3e98:c37d:b2f prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 52:b1:14:9b:ba:9d 
    inet6 fe80::50b1:14ff:fe9b:ba9d%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 52:b1:14:9b:ba:9d 
    inet6 fe80::50b1:14ff:fe9b:ba9d%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:85:0f:49:3c:05 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:85:0f:49:3c:04 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:85:0f:49:3c:01 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:85:0f:49:3c:00 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 94:05:bb:12:c2:08 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:85:0f:49:3c:01 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::9dd3:d1a7:af4b:51d3%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::567a:e7a9:23d9:794a%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1000
    inet6 fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x11 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Can you please help me on how to track down the issue? Let me know what other information you need.

Comment: I’m having similar problems. While troubleshooting I’ve found that while everything seems “unavailable,” I’m still able to load pages from http://www.Apple.com. Is this the same for you? Does it give you any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I didn't explicitly test apple.com so I can't make any statement on that. In my case I was able to solve the issue by re-installing the Apps "Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter" and "Cisco Secure Client". See my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more hours of investigating I think I've found the issue myself: In my case it seemed to be the "Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter" and/or "Cisco Secure Client" App that was installed on my laptop, even though they weren't active.

For reference here's a summary of the issues I experienced:

- `ping google.com` doesn't work at all or randomly loses packages
- fans are very loud, laptop is hot.
- in activity monitor we can see that a process `com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext` consumes a lot of cpu.

After I uninstalled the Cisco apps (Both "Secure Client" and "Socket Filter") the issues were gone and everyting worked normal again. (In Applications folder -> cisco/ I clicked on "Uninstall Any connect".

**How to reinstall Cisco if needed**

Maybe just a clean reinstall is enough. In my case I sticked to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420773/the-process-com-cisco-anyconnect-macos-acsockext-hogs-mac-cpu-but-cannot-be-kill) to make sure that `com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext` process is under control:

- I clicked `Don't allow` when asked: `Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter” Would Like to Filter Network Content`
- I simply uninstalled the Cisco Socket Filter App but kept Anyconnect client. In my case the Cisco App is working as needed, but this may of course be different in other scenarios.

Comment: Great work, [catching this filter that behaves differently when the OS advances](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/439889/5472) isn’t easy to do.